# Total number of pageviews in Google analytics of Angular web app

Tags: angular, google-analytics

I know that Angular is a single page app so I did something like this in app.component.ts

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log('event', event);
        gtag('config', 'xxx-xxxxxx-x', {
          page_title: event.urlAfterRedirects,
          page_location: event.urlAfterRedirects,
          page_path: event.urlAfterRedirects
        });
      }
    });
```

I can collect the data and see how many people are currently on that page under realtime section.
However, is there any way that I can get the total number of pageviews in Google analytics for angular pages? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the pageview event like :

```
gtag('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
gtag('send', 'pageview');
```

The gtag('config') should be call only one time on your app initialization, not on each router event..

Comment: I think I found what the problem I have. The default date selection of the behaviour section does not include current date. After I select the current date, data come up in behaviour section. Thank you for your reply though.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no accepted answer yet I am posting my solution.
In general there are two ways to achieve this:

1. Configure it in the index.html s head section:
   `gtag('config', 'YOUR GA ID', { send_page_view: true, anonymize_ip: false });`
2. Send a custom event looking like the following:

   `gtag('event', "page_view", {  page_title: document.title, page_location: window.location.href, page_path: window.location.pathname,});`